# How do you strip version numbers on resolved dependencies in gradle?

Tags: gradle

In the following gradle script using the ear plugin, how do I get file-war to not include the version number when it builds the ear?  Currently, it ends up building the ear but has the version number appended to file-war.war (e.g. file-war-13.war).

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

dependencies {
    compile "company:file-war:+"
    compile project(':MyWeb')
    deploy project(path: ':MyWeb', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy "company:file-war:+"
}

ear {
    deploymentDescriptor {
        webModule("MyWeb.war", "/")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  Since ear extends from jar, you can just use the rename method which allows you to provide a different name for any included resource.

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

dependencies {
    compile "company:file-war:+"
    compile project(':MyWeb')
    deploy project(path: ':MyWeb', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy "company:file-war:+"
}

ear {
    deploymentDescriptor {
        webModule("MyWeb.war", "/")
        webModule("MyNewName.war", "/context")
    }

    rename { f ->
       if (f.contains('file-war')) {
          return "MyNewName.war"
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ivestigate DSL [reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html) for `war` plugin.

This should work for instance:

```
war {
    version = ''       
}
```

Comment: The version does not appear to change the resolved dependency in this case.  In my ear, I still have file-war-13.war.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah. I've misunderstood. You need to do the same for `war` plugin.

Comment: I ended up providing an alternative way to address this.  Thanks for the help here.